# How to get data from uploaded input File object

Tags: javascript, html

In my Javascript, I have a File object using input type file, so I can get file name, file size, etc.  How do I get the File's actual data?

Answer (score 0):

You need to address the raw data by looking back to the Blob object.  See here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) object, e.g.

```
function readFile(thefile) {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        alert(e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(thefile);

}
```